# Error: Class computer comp is already defined in computer.obj

Tags: c++, lnk2005

I am currently playing with C++, and attempting to rebuild a Tic Tac Toe batch console game I made in C++, but have hit a wall, where I cannot figure out how to get rid of the error `TicTacToe.obj : error LNK2005: "class computer comp" (?comp@@3Vcomputer@@A) already defined in computer.obj`.  I have tried removing the declaration of the function computer from the header, and the definition of the function in the C++, but that didn't fix the error.  The only way I figured out how to remove this error was to remove the object name, which I kind of don't want to do.  I used the example given on the website http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/ to set up the class computer.  Any information you can provide on any errors that I currently have, or any functions I may not need are most definately welcome, as I am wanting to know much much more about C++.

CODE:

TicTacToe.cpp

```
// TicTacToe.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include "computer.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    comp.Select();
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

computer.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "computer.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

computer::computer()
{
}

computer::~computer()
{
}

void computer::Select()
{
}
```

computer.h

```
#pragma once
class computer
{
public:
    computer();
    ~computer();
    void Select(void);
} comp;
```

EXTRA INFO:

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 on a laptop running Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you included header `"computer.h"` in both modules `computer.cpp` and `TicTacToe.cpp` then the both modules contain the same definition of object `comp`

```
pragma once
class computer
{
public:
    computer();
    ~computer();
    void Select(void);
} comp;
```

So the linker issues the error.

Define the object only in one cpp module. The header should contain only the class definition.

For example

computer.h

```
#pragma once
class computer
{
public:
    computer();
    ~computer();
    void Select(void);
};
```

TicTacToe.cpp

```
// TicTacToe.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include "computer.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    computer comp;

    comp.Select();
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove comp from the header file. Create the object in a cpp file like this:

```
computer comp;
```

You said you don't want to do that. If that causes some other problem for you then post a new question about that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `comp` in the header, and so in every .cpp that includes that header, so you are breaking the One Definition Rule.

Instead you can declare it in the header:

```
extern computer comp;
```

And then define it in exactly one .cpp:

```
computer comp;
```

Which will still allow you to access it from any .cpp that includes the header.